# Disable rearranging rows in datagridview vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

is there an equivalent of allowusertoordercolumns property for datagridview rows? I have googled about it, all i could find was setting the read only property to true or setting allowdrop property to false. 
I want the user to be able to drag and drop into the datagrid view from other controls, but the rows should not be rearranged when the user drags and drops a row (by clicking the header row) within the same datagridview.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: How does the data get into the DGV?  In many cases reordering doesnt matter because it is just a VIEW of the data.

Comment: I'm loading dgv from sql table. I have some text in row header cell and i want in place.